# Subspaces, dimensions and images

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $L$ be a four-dimensional subspace to the five-dimensional vector space $V$, and $ A : V \to W $. Let $ A(L) $ be the subspace of W consisting of the vectors $ A(\bar{v}) $ in $W$ for which $ \bar{v} \in V $.
>
> Which possibilities exist for the dimension of the subspace $ A(L) $ of W, if $ \dim(\ker(A)) = 1 $?

First, we see that $ A(L) $ is simply *the image of $L$ under $A$*.

Thus, in the case that $L$ is the preimage of $A$, we have that $ A(L) = \mathrm{im}(A) $ and therefore according to the rank-nullity theorem,

$$ \dim(A(L)) = \dim(\mathrm{im}(A)) = \dim(V) - \dim(\ker(A)) = 4 $$

In the other case that $ L = \ker(A) $, we have that $ A(L) = 0 $ and therefore

$$ \dim(A(L)) = \dim(0) = 0.$$

It is in other words entirely possible for L to be the zero space, and for that reason $ A(L) $ could have zero dimensions. What we can show, however, is that $ A(L) $ cannot have more than four dimensions since it maps a five-dimensional space and has a one-dimensional kernel.

Does my reasoning seem correct? Did I miss anything?

Comment: It looks fine..

Comment: How can $L=\ker(A)$ since the former has dimension $4$ in $V$ and the latter has dimension $1$ in $V$?

Comment: Hmm, you're right. Also $ L = im(A) $ makes no sense either I suppose.

Answer (score 3):

This is close, but you've got a couple points of confusion. What we want to do is apply the rank-nullity theorem to $A$ restricted to $L$. Call this map $B.$ So, what's the kernel of $B$? Just the intersection of the kernel of $A$ with $L$, of course. This intersection could be either 1- or 0-dimensional, which gives us two corresponding possibilities for the dimension of $A(L)$.

Comment: So it's either three or four-dimensional?

Comment: Yep, you got it.